# Lista de datos ya no se muestra

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

Tengo un inconveniente, al momento de visualizar los datos asignados a un tipo de rol específico, ya no se muestran los datos de los demás, el campo se setea. tengo lo siguiente:
    //Carga el Rol y los permisos asociados según el ID

```
  $scope.loadPermissionFromRoleList = function(index){
    $scope.role = $scope.roles[index];
    permissionsTmp = new Array();
    for(i=0; i<$scope.permissions.length; i++){
        var isOut = true;
        for(j=0; j<$scope.role.permissions.length; j++){
            if($scope.permissions[i].name == $scope.role.permissions[j].name){
                isOut = false;
            }
        }
        if(isOut)
            permissionsTmp.push($scope.permissions[i]);
    }
    $scope.permissions = permissionsTmp;
    $scope.resetMessage();
}
```

Dentro de la vista

```
  <li data-ng-if="isPermited('ROLE_PERMISSION')"><a href="/#myModalRolePermission" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" title="" data-ng-click="loadPermissionFromRoleList($index)">Gestionar permisos</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas sobrescribiendo `$scope.permissions` con `permissionsTmp`, la segunda ves que llamas `$scope.loadPermissionFromRoleList`, solo contiene los permisos del rol anterior.

Guarda `permissionsTmp` en una variable diferente para que no borres tu lista de permisos original, por ejemplo:

```
$scope.currentPermissions = permissionsTmp;
```

Comment: Si, muchas gracias ahora se muestran todos los permisos, pero la idea es que se muestren no todos sino aquellos permisos que no fueron tomados en cuenta. No sé si me explico.

Comment: @CarmenA. Debes cambiar la vista donde muestras los permisos, para usar `$scope.currentPermissions` (que contiene solo los permisos actuales) en ves de `$scope.permissions` (que contiene todos los permisos).